# Displaying XML data selected from Combobox in Textbox C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

Hello I'm learning C# and I'm trying to show xml information from within User1.xml in a Textbox on the same form after it has been selected in the combobox.

I have managed to populate the combobox with the name tag using this code. (So that a username may be selected)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   XmlDocument sFor = new XmlDocument();
   sFor.Load(Path.GetFullPath("User1.xml"));
   XmlNodeList SearchList = sFor.SelectNodes("employee/user/name");
   foreach (XmlNode Search in SearchList)
   {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(Search.InnerText);
   }

}
```

**The XML is formatted thusly**

```
<employee>
    <user>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <department>PAI</department>
    <manager>MD</manager>
    <hours>full-time</hours>
    <leave>940</leave>
    </user>
</employee>
```

**How would I (Using linq or xmlreader or otherwise) after selection in the Combobox, display the information in textBox2?**

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to output the values from inside the XML, or the entire XML itself?

Comment: Where is `textBox2` defined?

Comment: Output information of the entire User In correlation with the user name selected from the combobox.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by define? textBox2 is within the same form that the other comboBox and textBox's and are initialized. Also to clarify, I want to display a single users details, department, manager, etc. The xml document contains multiple users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar with a DataGridView looking for a "City".  The input field was Textbox1.Text. I hope this isnt overkill. The credit goes to the posters here at Stack for showing me how to do this! I pulled the specific data first, then load it to a List. lastly, made the List the data source for DGV.  That might work for a combo box...yes?

```
<TaxTbl>
  <TaxSite>
    <Location>Axx</Location>
    <Address>xxx</Address>
    <City>aaa</City>
    <State> st</State>
    <Zip>xxx</Zip>
  </TaxSite>
  <TaxSite>
    <Location>Bxxx</Location>
    <Address>xxx</Address>
    <City>xxx</City>
    <State> st</State>
    <Zip>xxx</Zip>
  </TaxSite>
</TaxTbl>






 var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\Harley\\desktop\\outfile.xml");



var NewDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("TaxTbl",
             from anEntry in xdoc.Element("TaxTbl").Elements("TaxSite")
             where anEntry.Element("City").Value.Contains(textBox1.Text)
             select anEntry));



var MyList =
                    (from bEntry in NewDoc.Descendants("TaxSite")
                     select new
                     {
                         Location = bEntry.Element("Location").Value,
                         Address = bEntry.Element("Address").Value,
                         City = bEntry.Element("City").Value,
                         State = bEntry.Element("State").Value,
                         Zip = bEntry.Element("Zip").Value
                     }).ToList();


 cityDGV.DataSource = MyList.ToList();
```

Comment: I checked this with a ComboBox, and it did grab the data, WITH associated node tags. Bah.  like the previous answer, you could load variables WITH the node's inner text and then dump that into the combo box.

Comment: Hi I'm at the same point, I have managed to get the code to pull the xml data into an array like structure but I'm unsure how to repeat it into a textbox.

Comment: If you look at the 2nd part, similar to the 1st answer, where the element values are assigned to variables ... you MIGHT be able to put those values altogether as a string and add that string to your textbox output. OR... you could just break it down to labels for each variable  ie  Name label, Address label, city label  etc.  I hope my example was easy to understand.

Comment: I put the ToList I created into a textbox. Looks like ...textBox2.Text = MyList[0].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

If this can help you

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath("User1.xml"));

var rows = doc.Descendants("employee").Descendants("user").Select(el => new()
{
  department = el.Element("department").Value,
  manager = el.Element("manager").Value,
  hours = el.Element("hours").Value,
  leave = el.Element("leave").Value,
});
```

OR from DataSet like this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(new StreamReader("User1.xml"));
ds.ReadXml(new StreamReader("User1.xml"));
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this solution but receive a compiler error at line3 var rows = doc.Descendants("employee").Descendants("user").Select(el => new()  - At the double brackets it claims "Type expected". Removing the brackets () allows compilation but does not work as intended.